# Removing array duplicates based on second array item value

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to remove duplicates array's items (which are nested array's items) by comparing each of the second value (the date nested item, eg: `From 22/07/21 10:00 to 22/07/21 12:00`).

I'm struggling with it because the third nested item's value is a random string of character. Any help is appreciated.

Initial array:

```
[
  ['F-GMXB', 'From 22/07/21 10:00 to 22/07/21 12:00', 'M8202042500022072100000007'],
  ['F-HMRT', 'From 26/07/21 07:00 to 27/07/21 22:00', 'M8802052500023072100000004'],
  ['F-HMRT', 'From 26/07/21 07:00 to 27/07/21 22:00', 'M28681025000260C2100148836'],
  ['F-HMRT', 'From 26/07/21 07:00 to 27/07/21 22:00', 'M2868102500026072100128886'],
]
```

Expected result, new array:

```
[
  ['F-GMXB', 'From 22/07/21 10:00 to 22/07/21 12:00', 'M8202042500022072100000007'],
  ['F-HMRT', 'From 26/07/21 07:00 to 27/07/21 22:00', 'M8802052500023072100000004'],
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the previous dates in an array (`a`) and use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to check whether it includes it or not:

<sup>If it doesn't, add the date to the array</sup>

```js
const arr = [['F-GMXB', 'From 22/07/21 10:00 to 22/07/21 12:00', 'M8202042500022072100000007'],['F-HMRT', 'From 26/07/21 07:00 to 27/07/21 22:00', 'M8802052500023072100000004'],['F-HMRT', 'From 26/07/21 07:00 to 27/07/21 22:00', 'M28681025000260C2100148836'],['F-HMRT', 'From 26/07/21 07:00 to 27/07/21 22:00', 'M2868102500026072100128886']];

var a = [], res = arr.filter(e => !a.includes(e[1]) ? a.push(e[1]) : false);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Oh i see. My idea at firs was to get the position of each duplicated date and remove each key based on that. But your way is really ingenious! Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can also do that

```js
const arr1 =
[ ['F-GMXB', 'From 22/07/21 10:00 to 22/07/21 12:00', 'M8202042500022072100000007']
, ['F-HMRT', 'From 26/07/21 07:00 to 27/07/21 22:00', 'M8802052500023072100000004']
, ['F-HMRT', 'From 26/07/21 07:00 to 27/07/21 22:00', 'M28681025000260C2100148836']
, ['F-HMRT', 'From 26/07/21 07:00 to 27/07/21 22:00', 'M2868102500026072100128886']
]
const arr2 =  arr1.filter(( c,i,{[i-1]:p})=>( !i || c[1]!=p[1])  )
 

console.log(arr2)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100%!important;top:0 }
```